# How to create a new product with Lazada API?

Tags: php, vue.js

Below is the example code get from LazadaOP:

[Create function in ProductsController:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvFuK.png)

[Continue...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao5g8.png)

So I just try to run this but it shows the error with invalid request format.

[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtK3v.png)

I just want to know what is the problem with the code, and if there some solution plz do provide some code to references.TQ

Comment: Please put code into the Q, not as pic, and especially not as link to external pic  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@WilliamC, you had used a single quote on your XML string, yet your double quotes inside the string are escaped (e.g. `'<xml version=\"1.0\"...'`). You don't have to escape double quotes inside a single quoted string.

Should have been:
`'<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>...'`

More explanation about single vs. double quotes can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php).